# Magnetic Levitation Using Linear Hall Effect Sensors

Tags: arduino, sensor, hall-effect, electromagnetic

I am doing a project of magnetic levitation like this.[image]

I have two linear hall sensors which will give me the position of levitating magnet. I have set a specific position of magnetic object by reading the differential output of sensors at that position. After that i calculate the error and run the PID control algorithm to produce a signal that will goes to h bridge which will amplify the signal and provide supply to electromagnet according to control signal. Control signal will be larger if floating magnet will too far and smaller if too neer.But I am not able to levitate an object. 
 Anyone did this? Please come forward and help me. I will provide more details if required.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjjBqzilkIc

Comment: Hi Waseem, provide more details, it is required.

Comment: Sir, i have updated question. If you have any question ask me.

Comment: You have shown us a photo of someone else's setup. His is working. Show _your_ setup. You haven't said what is working and what isn't. Please try and imagine what information your reader would need to help you. Then add the information in your original question.

Comment: You need to test each piece of the system and make sure its working. For example, make sure your actually getting the correct position from the hall effect sensors.

Answer (score 4):

I have done this successfully, but with just a single linear hall effect sensor. I used a position sensing scheme where the field strength of the magnet being levitated was sampled synchronously with the electromagnet PWM, in such a way that the measurements were taken only when the electromagnet current had decayed to zero.

This might be hard to program with the arduino environment, but using the plain AVR-GCC compiler it is trivial to trigger an interrupt for ADC sampling slightly before the end of each PWM cycle.

The sensor was mounted directly on the bottom of the electromagnet. Feeding the field strength samples directly to a PID controller is not optimal, as the readings do not correlate linearly with distance. Thus I calculated a distance estimate with a 10 point linearization curve.

Update:

> 1-How can we detect PWM's falling edge using internal interrupt ?

You use timer/counter 1 in fast PWM mode, set the output compare unit A to generate the PWM waveform and set the output compare unit B to generate an interrupt a few cycles before the timer overflows (and the next PWM pulse begins). You write an interrupt handler that responds to that interrupt by starting an ADC conversion.

> 2-Which type of control strategy you used i.e PID or something else.

A single PID control loop.

> 3-How can we estimate distance with linearization curve.

3) You move the magnet to a known distance, write down the ADC output, move the magnet 1mm closer, write down the output and repeat until you have covered the entire levitation range. Then in your program you find the two closest known values to the ADC reading, and linearly interpolate between the two to estimate the distance in that range.

Comment: Thank you sir. I understood your logic but i have some questions here.  1-How can we detect PWM's falling edge using internal interrupt ?  2-Which type of control strategy you used i.e PID or something else.  3-How can we estimate distance with linearization curve.

Comment: @Waseem Usman See updated answer. I am on mobile, I cannot write a more comprehensive answer, but I can respond to questions.

Comment: @jms: Does this work by sensing the field of the suspended magnet during the 'off' periods?

Comment: @jms I will try this and will inform you about outcomes. Sir i have directly connected the arduino 5v to Hall sensor A1302 Vcc and also ouput pin of hall sensor directly to adc pin of arduino without any filter. What is your suggestion either i have to filter output or just leave it unfiltered.

Comment: @jms how many times i must have to read adc in a second?

Comment: @Waseem Usman do not filter the Hall effect sensor output. If you do, the electromagnet duty cycle will affect the readings as the sensor output will fluctuate wildly when there is current in the coil. The higher the control loop update rate is, the better. I found out that 100 Hz is the bare minimum. I sampled the ADC on every PWM cycle in my project. The important part is to sample only when the electromagnet carries zero current. If you want, you *can* low pass filter the sensor output, but you must do so in the digital domain, e.g. with a finite impulse response filter.

Comment: @Transistor Correct. I found out that it works just fine. Obviously it does have drawbacks: analog filtering is impossible, the current has to decay to zero during each cycle so high duty cycles are not possible and the software becomes more complex.

Comment: @jms Sir you are awesome, i have successfully read the ADC value of floating magnet without any effect of electromagnet's field.

Comment: @jms sir how have you tuned your PID for maglev?

Comment: @WaseemUsman By hand. Start with all gains zero, increase P until the magnet is picked up when the controller is started, increase D until stability is achieved and increase I until any steady state error is corrected within a few seconds. P is the main control term, I corrects the steady state offset an D dampens magnet movements.

Comment: Where should i use linearization curve in program?

Comment: @jms I find (affordable, i.e. around 0.1-5$ pp) hall sensors are usually only sensitive in the ~0.1-2cm range. Would you share what hall sensor you used and / or which one you recommend for this project?

Comment: @user2305193 Indeed my system only achieved a distance in that range (around 8 mm). I used [this sensor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/allegro-microsystems/A1324LUA-T/2728144) and a neodymium magnet in the payload.